# file not run from browser but run from terminal

Tags: php, linux, file

Below is my code which show error while running from browser but it is successfully run from terminal. It is goes in die condition. But while I run this code from linux terminal below code is successfully executed. I am running this code from linux machine. What is the reason behind code is not running from browser?

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: It's working for me,  have you checked the directory permissions?

Comment: It's working from terminal because you have privileges to create files as root (or your user). But you don't have permission to create files via HTTP request due to insufficient permission.

Comment: Try: http://php.net/function.chmod

Comment: correct my problem is solved.

Comment: please write same on answer

Comment: Glad to know it's got working, added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working from terminal because you have privileges to create files as root (or your user). But you don't have permission to create files via HTTP request due to insufficient permission.

If the problem persists, check this: http://php.net/function.chmod